# selecting checkbox and passing the value on clicking button

Tags: php, html

I have a table with checkbox in its rows,after selecting checkbox, and clicking on button, I want to get a new page,and print the selected row details.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exec_escalations");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
<table border="1" >
<tr>
    <td><h3select<h3</td>
    <td><h3>Date<h3></td>
    <td><h3>Address<h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['s_id']; ?>" />              </td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['address']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

this is my button:

```
<input type="button" name="issue" value="Issue Notice" onClick="location.href='address.php'" />
```

address.php:

```
<?php
echo"hi";
$n=$_GET['ID'];
echo"$n";
?>
```

How can I pass the selected row values to other page and print using checkbox, kindly help me, Please....

Comment: Questions are asked in this site so that mistakes are corrected, If anyone has to vote down,Have courtesy to  mention the reason atleast !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change name="ID" to name="ID[]" in all of your input tags and then handle the $_GET['ID'] variable as an array.

HTML

```
<form action="address.php" method="GET">
.
.
<input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $row['s_id'];?> "/>
.
.
 <input type="submit" name="issue" value="Issue Notice" />
</form>
```

You can eheck IDs using print_r($_GET['ID']);

PHP

```
<?php 

  if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
   print_r($_GET['ID']);
  }

?>
```

Comment: Its still not coming :( it gives :Undefined index: ID in D:\XAMPP\address.php on line 5

Comment: have you followed my template given in this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You've started a loop, but put the HTML directly inside the PHP without outputting it. Since your checkbox is maintaining the same name with each iteration of your loop, you must make it an array to hold multiple values. You were also creating a new table with each loop which I don't believe was intended.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<table border="1" >
<tr>
    <td><h3>select<h3></td>
    <td><h3>Date<h3></td>
    <td><h3>Address<h3></td>
</tr>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exec_escalations");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="'.$row['s_id'].'" /></td>
    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```